# How to remove an onion service from the DHT?

Tags: onion-services

Btw, I am a newbie so I am sorry if this is a dumbest question, but here I come!

So, I am trying to learn about tor's onion services from their website on [this page](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/overview/) and how it's actually done on [this page](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/). From my understanding, when I run `tor`, my service registers itself on tor's distributed hash table and at those introduction points and saves data about it in a folder so I can reuse it when I run `tor` for the next time. I am concluding that the registration does not expire and stays there even after I terminate my `tor`. Now since it is all anonymous, I don't really have a limit of how many services I can set up and register and that means I can set up hundreds of them every day...
My question is now: how do onion services get removed? Is there some time limit of how long my service can be inactive before it gets removed from the DHT? That would make sense to me, but I couldn't confirm by searching the internet so I am asking here.

Comment: I have checked on their RFC and yes, there is a time limit and it is 3 hours. But I don't want to post this as an answer, maybe someone knows how to actually manually remove it...

Comment: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/torspec/-/blob/main/spec/rend-spec/deriving-keys.md#expiring-hidden-service-descriptors-expire-desc